# Obtain upper bound on nonnegative non-increasing integrand $f(t)$ from bound of its integral $\int_{0}^\infty f(t)dt \le W$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f:[0,\infty) \mapsto [0, 1]$ be a non-increasing function and $W > 0$ be such that

$$
\int_{0}^\infty f(t)dt \le W.
\tag{1}
$$

**Goal.** I seek nontrivial upper-bounds on $f(t)$.

It is easy to deduce that

$$
f(t) \le \frac{W}{t},\forall t > 0.
\tag{2}
$$
Indeed, for every $t > 0$, we have $tf(t) \le \int_0^tf(s)ds \le \int_0^\infty f(s)ds \le W$.

> **Question.** Apart from inequality (2), are there any nontrivial upper-bounds on $f(t)$ which can be obtained from (1) ?

Answer (score 1):

For $t > W$, there is no better upper bound for $f(t)$. You can think of the following function 
\begin{equation*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 W/t\qquad \text{if } x \in [0, t],\\
0 \hspace{3.5em} \text{if } x > t. 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
It satisfies your condition with $f(t) = W/t$.

For $t < W$, the better upper bound is given by $1$ (since $W/t > 1$). In summary, the optimal upper bound for $f$ is 
$$f(t) \leq 1 \wedge W/t.$$

In addition, I think this optimal bound will not change even if you assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ya, indeed. On second thought, my question's a bit naughty (= didn't think about it much). Without strong assumptions on $f$, the bound (2) can't be improved. Upvoted.